# How do I pause the animation in React Spring?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-spring

I'm trying to pause the animation in React Spring after 3 seconds,
I tried the following code but it didn't work.

````js
                      const pb = props => {
                        const spring = useSpring({
                            from: {
                                progress: 0
                            },
                            to: {
                                progress: 100
                            },
                            pause: _ => {
                            setTimout(() => {
                            return true
                            },3000)
},
                            config: { duration: props.timeout ?? 3000 },
                        });

                        console.log(spring);
                        const style = {
                            width: spring.progress.to(e => `${e}%`), 
                        };
                        return (
                            React.createElement(animated.div, {...props,
                            style: {
                                ...style,
                                ...props.style
                            }
                            })```
````

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of react-spring `v9.2` you can use `useSpring` and pass it a function that return the `styles` and `api` to control the animation state, using this `api` we can easily pause and resume an animation

```
function TestComponent() {

  const [pause, setPause] = useState(false);

  const [styles, api] = useSpring(() => ({
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    to: { opacity: 1 },
    config: {
      mass: 18.6,
      tension: 7,
      friction: 161
    },
  }))

  return (
    <>
      <animated.div style={styles}>
        {'Fade in effect'}
      </animated.div>

      <button onClick={() => { api.pause() }}>{'pause'}</button>
      <button onClick={() => { api.resume() }}>{'resume'}</button>
    </>
  );

}
```

you can see how the result becomes
[image]

in case you want to pause after `3 seconds` you can use `useEffect` with `setTimeout`

```
function TextComponentTimeout() {

  const [pause, setPause] = useState(false);

  const [styles, api] = useSpring(() => ({
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    to: { opacity: 1 },
    config: {
      mass: 18.6,
      tension: 7,
      friction: 161
    },
  }))

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      api.pause();
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <animated.div style={styles}>
        {'Fade in effect'}
      </animated.div>

    </>
  );

}
```